# Reading license file from RLM with C# (C++ to C# translation)

Tags: c#, c++, file-io, license-key

I'm using the Reprise RLM license manager researching internet activation. I can't figure out how to get the license file from the webserver into a text file with C# (I'm also very new to C#).

RLM comes with an example in C++ but I can't translate it.

My code (for the demo) looks like so:

```
int stat = RLM.rlm_act_request(handle, "http://www.reprisesoftware.com", "rlmactdemo", activationKey, "", "", 1, "", new byte[RLM.RLM_MAX_LINE+1]);
if (stat == 0||stat == 1){
   //Successful connection
   //Read license file and write to local machine
}
```

`rlm_act_request` establishes and verifies the connection.  Once it is established, how do I access the file and write it a local file?

The C++ code for whatever goes in that if statement is as follows:

```
char name[100];
char license[100];
int try;
FILE *f, *fopen();
stat = 1;

for (try=0; try<100; try++)
{
    sprintf(name, "a%d.lic", try);
    f = fopen(name, "r");
    if (f == (FILE *) NULL)
    {
        f = fopen(name, "w");
        if (f)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%s\n", license);
            fclose(f);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error writing license file \"%s\"\n", name);
            stat = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the C# equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was surprisingly easy.  It turns out that the 'new byte[]' that gets passes to rml_act_request() holds the contents of the license file.  All I had to do was make it a local variable, convert it to string and write it to file using TextWriter.WriteLine();

I wish this had been documented somewhere...